# Jersey Server Request/Response filter thread safe

Tags: jersey-2.0

I want to add some MDC logging to all my REST requests and I am using jersey.  I have seen some examples of this online but I can't find any info on the thread safety of doing this:
https://coderwall.com/p/qjwyya/jax-rs-mapped-diagnostic-context-filter

```
 @Provider
public class HttpMDCRequestListener implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {


  @Override
  public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) throws IOException {
    MDC.put("test", "blah");
  }

  @Override
  public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext,
      ContainerResponseContext containerResponseContext) throws IOException {
    MDC.clear();
  }
```

Is there a new instance of this class for each request?  I want to make sure I am clearing the MDC on the same thread as the request.

thanks

Comment: I realized after I posted this that the thread safety doesn't matter.  MDC is thread local and I am only clearing the MDC values for whatever thread hits the method, not using any values from the thread local variables.

Comment: There is one filter instance for the entire application.